# a log-out hyperlink in PHP?

Tags: php

In case somebody knows, how can I make a hyperlink in PHP...

```
<?php
  echo( '<a href="index.php">Log-out</a>' );
?>
```

that would not only to navigate to the first page, but also remove cookies?

Thanks!

Comment: I've been following all your questions, and you really need to read a tutorial and/or the PHP documentation.  You're continuously asking basic questions which are easily answered if you simply learned PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit a parameter in your link like `index.php?logout=true`, check for that parameter in your index.php and if set, delete cookies:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.setcookie.php

If you set the "lifetime" (expire) of a cookie to something in the past (or leave it out completely), it will be removed on the next pageload (do a Google search for "php delete cookie" to find help). Force a page reload, if needed.

You may also want to destroy the user's session.

Answer (score 4):

You can make another page which clears all the cookies (i.e. sets them to expire in the past) and then redirects to `index.php`:

```
// page: clear.php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();

setcookie('cookie1', '', strtotime('-2 days'));
setcookie('cookie2', '', strtotime('-2 days'));
// etc.
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the method prescribed by the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

```
<?php
// Initialize the session.
// If you are using session_name("something"), don't forget it now!
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables.
$_SESSION = array();

// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// Finally, destroy the session.
session_destroy();
?>
```

The only thing that remains is `header('Location: index.php');`

Answer (score 1):

Here's your HTML link

```
<a href="index.php?logout">Log-out</a>
```

And your PHP to handle to logging out

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    // clear the session variable, display logged out message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use link like that:

```
<?php
  echo( '<a href="index.php?link=logout">Log-out</a>' );
?>
```

And index.php is:

```
<?php
  $link = $_GET["link"];
  if($link == "logout")
  {
     session_destroy();
  }
?>
```

Comment: As well as `session_destroy`, you should also redirect the user and then `exit()`. Otherwise, the user won't appear logged out until they reload the page or load another.

Answer (score 1):

In the navigation menu:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log out</a>
```

In `logout.php`:

```
<?php
// kill the session
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

For killing the session, see the example at [session_destroy()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

Logout Link:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```